# Joomla smtp can't connect to host

Tags: joomla, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I am curently wabmaster at a student association and got mailing working. However the day after it would't work anymore. I can't find any real error codes in the smtp log and the host says it doesn't block this service.
This is the log:

```
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] Connection: opening to smtp.googlemail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array (
)
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] Connection: opened
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220-sh3.hosty.nl ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:34:27 +0100 
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-sh3.hosty.nl ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:34:27 +0100 
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-sh3.hosty.nl ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:34:27 +0100 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220 and/or bulk e-mail.
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-sh3.hosty.nl ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:34:27 +0100 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO example.com

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-SIZE 52428800
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
250-SIZE 52428800
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-8BITMIME
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-PIPELINING
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-STARTTLS
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250 HELP
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220 TLS go ahead
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "221 sh3.hosty.nl closing connection
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 sh3.hosty.nl closing connection

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] Connection: closed
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] Connection: opening to smtp.googlemail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array (
)
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] Connection: opened
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220-sh3.hosty.nl ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:34:27 +0100 
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-sh3.hosty.nl ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:34:27 +0100 
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-sh3.hosty.nl ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:34:27 +0100 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220 and/or bulk e-mail.
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-sh3.hosty.nl ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Mon, 06 Feb 2017 14:34:27 +0100 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO example.com

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-SIZE 52428800
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
250-SIZE 52428800
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-8BITMIME
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-PIPELINING
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250-STARTTLS
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "250 HELP
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-sh3.hosty.nl Hello sh3.hosty.nl [185.69.233.117]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "220 TLS go ahead
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is  "221 sh3.hosty.nl closing connection
"
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 sh3.hosty.nl closing connection

[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] Connection: closed
[06-Feb-2017 14:34:27 Europe/Amsterdam] SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

The solution to disable smtp mail doesn't work because with phpmailing we can only send 1 mail per hour.

Comment: It would really help if you read the documentation. `SMTPDebug = 4` is unnecessarily noisy for this problem (you're not having a connection issue). You have a TLS problem, which is covered extensively in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). The fact that your error output doesn't include a link to it tells me that you're using an old, probably vulnerable, version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: @Synchro I downloaded the backup and on my localhost it works

Comment: Right, because your local TLS config isn't broken. Fix TLS on your server and PHPMailer will be able to work.

Comment: @Synchro These aren't in the joomla files?

Comment: No, it's to do with the config of PHP itself on your server. Compare the output of `phpinfo()` on both and spot the differences.

Comment: @Synchro The TLs settings are exactly the same

Comment: OK, so do what the troubleshooting guide says and use openssl to check the connection.

Comment: @Synchro I did everything in the troubleshooting guide but still not working. I have openSSL enabled

Answer (score 0):

You're asking to connect to `smtp.googlemail.com`, but it's connecting to `sh3.hosty.nl`; this means your ISP is intercepting your traffic and redirecting you to their mail server, which of course fails to match the name you asked to connect to, causing a TLS failure.

[This exact scenario](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#firewall-redirection) is covered in the troubleshooting guide the error links you to. You need to ask your ISP how you should send email; they may provide a gateway service via their own mail server.

Comment: So the host is blocking it?

Comment: They're not blocking it, they are redirecting it to their own mail server, which causes it to fail the hostname check on the certificate, hence the TLS failure.